# double root of a quartic rational polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Let  $p(x)$ be a degree $4$ polynomial with rational coefficients. Suppose I know that it has a double real root $\alpha$. Does it then follow that $\alpha$ is in fact rational?

I excpect a counterexample but I couldn't find one and also not much upon searching internet. Any clarification appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: Take $p(x)=x^4-6x^2+9=(x^2-3)^2$ which has irrational double roots.

Comment: oh true. thank you

Comment: is it possible that it factors like $(x - \alpha)^2 Q$ where $Q$ is degree $2$ with no real roots and $\alpha$ is irrational?